# How to properly retry on HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I have a method that sends `POST` requests to a server.
The request is defined in the `HttpRequestMessage` object.

Yet, if the server returns some *retryable* error, I would like to retry, as the following code does:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _endpoint))
{
    var requestPayload = Serialize(ingestionRequest);
    request.Content = new StringContent(requestPayload, Encoding.UTF8, JsonContentType);

    await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        // ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
        using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new IngestionException(response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It turns out that an `HttpRequestMessage` cannot be sent more than once, throwing the following exception:

> The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times.

How could I do what's the above code tries to do - **while keeping the code simple and elegant?**

Answer (score 1):

Try copying/cloning the request message using something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18014515/112247). Then use the cloned request on the next retry. Something like

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var oldRequest = request;
  request = request.Clone();
  oldRequest.Dispose();
  throw new IngestionException(response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```